# a tag as a submit button?

Tags: html, button, tags

Hi I am trying to get "a" tag as a submit button.  I found a code somewhere in the web. But it didn't work.

```
<a href="#" onclick="this.form.submit()">Submit</a>
```

Is there any code for to achieve my need?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Give the `form` an `id`, and then:

`document.getElementById("yourFormId").submit();`

Best practice would probably be to give your link an `id` too, and get rid of the event handler:

```
document.getElementById("yourLinkId").onclick = function() {
    document.getElementById("yourFormId").submit();
}
```

Comment: @James Allardice Can this be accomplished in Jquery?

Answer (score 40):

Try this code:

```
<form id="myform">
  <!-- form elements -->
  <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit()">Submit</a>
</form>
```

But users with disabled JavaScript won't be able to submit the form, so you could add the following code:

```
<noscript>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form!" />
</noscript>
```

Answer (score 18):

Supposing the form is the direct parent you can do:

```
<a href='#' onclick='this.parentNode.submit(); return false;'>submit</a>
```

If not you can access through the forms name attribute like this:

```
<a href='#' onclick='document.forms["myform"].submit(); return false;'>submit</a>
```

See both examples here: http://jsfiddle.net/WEZDC/1/

Comment: Or use [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) to get the closest form: `<a href="#" onclick="this.closest('form').submit(); return false;">`

Answer (score 8):

This is an improve of @ComFreek ans:

```
<form id="myform">
  <!-- form elements -->
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="document.getElementById('myform').submit()">Submit</a>
</form>
```

So the  will not trigger action and reload your page. Specially if your are developing with a framework with SPA.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below

```
 <a href="#" onclick="this.forms['formName'].submit()">Submit</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById('myForm').action="javascript:function("+a+","+b+")";

You can change the action attribute, and put some variables as params of a function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -6):

in my opinion the easiest way would be somthing like this:

```
<?php>
echo '<a href="link.php?submit='.$value.'">Submit</a>';
</?>
```

within the "link.php" you can request the value like this:

```
$_REQUEST['submit']
```

Comment: What if the form action is not GET?

Comment: Why would you want to use echo to create html? Just do this
<a href="link.php?submit='<?php echo $value; ?>">Submit</a>

Comment: @sneilan is there a difference on performance?