# html - make a <p> tag trigger the form submit

Tags: html, forms

How do you make an element like `<p>` or similar trigger the form submission. I do not want to use a button.

Is there a way?

```
<form>
    <p>I want this to be clicked to submit the form</p>
    <input type='submit' value='Not this one. This is too cliche for me'>
</form>
```

Comment: `$('p').click(function(){$('form).submit();});`

Comment: Yes you can, but since a `<p>` tag is not a clickable element per se (unlike `<button>` or `<a>` or `<input>`), you will need to rely on JS to perform the click event binding to submit the form programmatically. The real question is, *why do you want rely on a `<p>` tag to submit the form*? There is no reason to do that.

Comment: You need to use Click event for a tag `<p onclick="this.form.submit()">I want this to be clicked to submit the form</p>`

Answer (score 0):

I guess an *a* tag could work: [a tag as a submit button?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7340300/9047620)

You would just need to put it in the *p* tag