# jQuery: how can I pass this to my function on click button?

Tags: html, jquery

Below code works properly until I insert new row by jQuery. 'delete' button doesn't work in my new row.

```js
$(".delete").on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td> <input type="text" /></td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="delete btn btn-danger btn-xs" type="button">
          <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Why pass an event to an element? After all, you can make it easier ..
`$('.up.btn.btn-primary.btn-xs').on('click', function(){$(this).parents("tr:first");});`

Comment: I changed my code above to show more description.

Comment: Judging by the code, do you want to delete the line you clicked on?

Comment: Can you post the code to insert the row?

Comment: @sergey kuznetsov : Exactly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7340300/a-tag-as-a-submit-button/7340340

Comment: I found the answer in this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420558/jquery-click-event-not-working-after-append-method

Answer (score 1):

If you add new row dynamicly, you have to bind like this;

```
$(document).on("click",".delete", function() {...
```

Cause you need bind dynamic created element.